# return a substring in function(c)

Tags: c, string, char

I do not know why the following method does not work.the printf function in main method does not output substring "love".I Just allocate a char* inside function.and return it in the return value

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char *sub_str(char* str,int start,int end) {
//return  substring from pos start to end(included)
   char *a=str;
   char *s=(char*)malloc((end-start+1)*sizeof(char));
   for(int i=0;i<start;i++)
   a++;
   for(int i=start;i<=end;i++){
      *s++=*a++;
   }
   return s;
}

int main() {
char *str="I love apples";
char *c=sub_str(str,2,5);
printf("%s",c);
}
```

Comment: Three additional suggestion (1) don't cast returned address from malloc and calloc in C, and (2) you don't need extra variable `a`, you could use `str `  (3) you don't need first for loop just add index to `a`.

Comment: yes，a is not necessary,as the modification to str is only effective inside function.loop is also unnecessary.as the address can be got using `str+start`

Comment: Note that if the string is null terminated, the memory allocation is insufficient.  For the example, (5 - 2 + 1) is 4, adequate for `love` but not for the null terminator too.  That's over and above the issues identified in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
for(int i=start;i<=end;i++){
        *s++=*a++;
}
```

You are moving s. Hence it is not working. When you return, s does not point to the beginning of the substring or to memory allocated using malloc.

Comment: Don't forget your null terminator on the newly string s.

Comment: also when does the memory get freed? It would generate on every function call a memory leak

Comment: +1 Apart from that, `a` is worthless in the posted OPs code. We can just use `str`, which should also be `const char*`. Likewise is for-loop run-up iteration, as we can just `str += start` to position the copy source before the real copy happens.